# Python remove enter / space between lines

Tags: python, space, enter

OK so I have read a lot of the post that suggest how to eliminate that extra space, but for whatever reason it seems I can't apply those suggestions to my system, so I am here asking for your help.

These are the last few lines of my code:

```
    for line in rline[start+5 : end] :
        words = line.split()
        word1 = int(words[1])
        print >>opennew, "%s%s" % (word1,line[30:])
```

And the new "opennew" file looks like this :

```
    1        0.876153    0.152889   -0.047464

    2        1.011880   -1.161641   -2.096289

    3        0.883419    1.558736    1.966913

    4        2.010367   -1.140725    1.053368
```

While what I really want is:

```
    1        0.876153    0.152889   -0.047464
    2        1.011880   -1.161641   -2.096289
    3        0.883419    1.558736    1.966913
    4        2.010367   -1.140725    1.053368
```

Is there anyway I add to the code something to remove that additional (unwanted) enter/space from my input?

Thanks a lot for the help.

PS: 
(Please do not ask why I split the lines in the code, there is a purpose for this will have an application in a future (better) code)

Answer (score 7):

Try stripping the newlines off of `line`:

```
line = line.rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything different on Windows.

Comment: @martineau Really?  I thought you would need to remove a carriage return as well for Windows files.  I could be wrong, as I have no way of testing it.

Comment: If data is read or written from/to a file in non-binary text mode, the default `open()` mode, conversion from/to the platform's line-ending convention is currently handled for you automatically in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can either remove the trailing whitespace from each line using `line = line.rstrip()` or change the `print` statement to omit its own trailing linebreak:

```
print >>opennew, "%s%s" % (word1,line[30:]),
#                                          ^
```

However, due to the convoluted syntax of the `print` statement it is probably better to use `rstrip()`...

Comment: I do like `print whatever,` but agree it's sometimes too subtle (or just removed because it's not understood and presumed *wrong*). Only slight point is the OP may want `.rstrip('\n')` if for some reason trailing whitespace is significant

Comment: He's dumping a human-readable table in plaintext to stdout. So trailing whitespace is most likely not significant and usually also not wanted e.g. in case of redirecting the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThiefMaster or @squiguy suggested, but another way is:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('%s%s' % (word1, line[30:]))
```

Although I'd probably go for `.rstrip`

Comment: Thanks all of you for the suggestions, based on ThiefMaster answer it occur to me that I could just eliminate the last white space from the line by adding a "-1", instead of eliminating the Python own linebreak, with this the problem was fixed

        print >>opennew, "%s%s" % (word1,line[30:-1])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for the suggestions, based on ThiefMaster answer it occur to me that I could just eliminate the last white space from the line by adding a "-1", instead of eliminating the Python own linebreak, with this the problem was fixed

```
    print >>opennew, "%s%s" % (word1,line[30:-1])
```

Another way I tried before was

```
    opennew.write (str(word1) + (line[30:]) + "")
```

The additional quotes at the end are the ones that eliminate that additional (unwanted) enter/space. It worked for me, but honestly I do not know why, do you know what those additional quotes do?

Thanks